# Media deployment advice

Tags: deployment, static-content, media

We have applications that have a lot of static content (>60gb) which is updated frequently.  It used to be we would manually rsync from vendors and between environments, and our code would rely on naming conventions to find files.  Only now are we writing tools that will help with media ingestion, using a database to store filenames.

We still have the problem of keeping tabs on our media across environments and servers.  I'm wondering if anyone can share how they keep on top of large amounts of static media content, and how they automate deployment.  We only have a couple devs and dev ops, so lightweight, simple solutions are always preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Well the easy solution is to use star topology. You ingest media to big origin server, and it's replicated across small edge servers.

Ideally you would use XML files to store meta-data with each file on the filesystem. In database you can have index of these.